# Clean Eclipse RCP workbench at startup

Tags: eclipse-rcp

How to have an Eclipse RCP application always have a clean workbench at startup?

I just want the ViewParts to be hidden, not unrestored, so the switch to clear workbench data is not what I need.

I try to hide all views on `postWindowCreate` in the `WorkbenchWindowsAdvisor` and it works good for all views but one, it is as if I can't hide them all at this stage of the workbench creation.

Code for hiding views (latest attempt):

```
IWorkbenchWindow[] windows = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                .getWorkbenchWindows();
for (IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow : windows) {
    IWorkbenchPage[] pages = workbenchWindow.getPages();
    for (IWorkbenchPage iWorkbenchPage : pages) {
        IViewReference[] viewReferences = iWorkbenchPage
                .getViewReferences();
        for (IViewReference iViewReference : viewReferences) {
            IWorkbenchPart part = iViewReference.getPart(true);
            if (part instanceof ISaveablePart2) {
                iWorkbenchPage.hideView((IViewPart) part);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
The view in question gets its `createPartControl` called even though no other of my views have their `createPartControl` called. It is called after `postWindowCreate` and `postWindowOpen`, stack trace:

```
CreativeAssistantView.createPartControl(Composite) line: 106    
CompatibilityView(CompatibilityPart).createPartControl(IWorkbenchPart, Composite) line: 142 
CompatibilityView.createPartControl(IWorkbenchPart, Composite) line: 174    
CompatibilityView(CompatibilityPart).create() line: 323 
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 57  
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 43  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 606  
MethodRequestor.execute() line: 56  
InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(Class<Annotation>, Object, Class<?>, PrimaryObjectSupplier, PrimaryObjectSupplier, ArrayList<Class<?>>) line: 877 
InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(Class<Annotation>, Object, Class<?>, PrimaryObjectSupplier, PrimaryObjectSupplier, ArrayList<Class<?>>) line: 857 
InjectorImpl.inject(Object, PrimaryObjectSupplier, PrimaryObjectSupplier) line: 119 
InjectorImpl.internalMake(Class<?>, PrimaryObjectSupplier, PrimaryObjectSupplier) line: 333 
InjectorImpl.make(Class<T>, PrimaryObjectSupplier) line: 254    
ContextInjectionFactory.make(Class<T>, IEclipseContext) line: 162   
ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(Bundle, IEclipseContext, IEclipseContext, URI) line: 102 
ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(String, IEclipseContext, IEclipseContext) line: 71   
ReflectionContributionFactory.create(String, IEclipseContext) line: 53  
ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(MUIElement, Object) line: 129  
PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(MUIElement, Object) line: 949  
PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(MUIElement, Object, IEclipseContext) line: 633    
PartRenderingEngine$6.run() line: 526   
SafeRunner.run(ISafeRunnable) line: 42  
PartRenderingEngine.createGui(MUIElement, Object, IEclipseContext) line: 511    
ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(MUIElement, Object) line: 61  
PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(MUIElement, Object) line: 949  
PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(MUIElement, Object, IEclipseContext) line: 633    
PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(MUIElement) line: 735 
PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine, MUIElement) line: 706 
PartRenderingEngine$7.run() line: 700   
SafeRunner.run(ISafeRunnable) line: 42  
PartRenderingEngine.createGui(MUIElement) line: 685 
PartRenderingEngine$1.handleEvent(Event) line: 134  
UIEventHandler$1.run() line: 41 
UISynchronizer(Synchronizer).syncExec(Runnable) line: 180   
UISynchronizer.syncExec(Runnable) line: 150 
Display.syncExec(Runnable) line: 4688   
E4Application$1.syncExec(Runnable) line: 205    
UIEventHandler.handleEvent(Event) line: 38  
EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(Event, Permission) line: 197    
EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerWrapper, Permission, int, Event) line: 197    
EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(Object, Object, int, Object) line: 1  
EventManager.dispatchEvent(Set<Entry<K,V>>, EventDispatcher<K,V,E>, int, E) line: 230   
ListenerQueue<K,V,E>.dispatchEventSynchronous(int, E) line: 148 
EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(Event, boolean) line: 135  
EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(Event) line: 78    
EventComponent.sendEvent(Event) line: 39    
EventBroker.send(String, Object) line: 80   
UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(Notification) line: 58   
PlaceholderImpl(BasicNotifierImpl).eNotify(Notification) line: 374  
PlaceholderImpl(UIElementImpl).setToBeRendered(boolean) line: 290   
ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(MWindow, MUIElement) line: 574 
ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(MUIElement) line: 543   
PartServiceImpl.switchPerspective(MPerspective) line: 504   
PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(MUIElement) line: 124  
PerspectiveStackRenderer(LazyStackRenderer).postProcess(MUIElement) line: 97    
PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(MUIElement) line: 77   
PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(MUIElement, Object, IEclipseContext) line: 649    
PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(MUIElement) line: 735 
PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine, MUIElement) line: 706 
PartRenderingEngine$7.run() line: 700   
SafeRunner.run(ISafeRunnable) line: 42  
PartRenderingEngine.createGui(MUIElement) line: 685 
SashRenderer(SWTPartRenderer).processContents(MElementContainer<MUIElement>) line: 61   
PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(MUIElement, Object, IEclipseContext) line: 645    
PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(MUIElement) line: 735 
PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine, MUIElement) line: 706 
PartRenderingEngine$7.run() line: 700   
SafeRunner.run(ISafeRunnable) line: 42  
PartRenderingEngine.createGui(MUIElement) line: 685 
WBWRenderer(SWTPartRenderer).processContents(MElementContainer<MUIElement>) line: 61    
WBWRenderer.processContents(MElementContainer<MUIElement>) line: 676    
PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(MUIElement, Object, IEclipseContext) line: 645    
PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(MUIElement) line: 735 
PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine, MUIElement) line: 706 
PartRenderingEngine$7.run() line: 700   
SafeRunner.run(ISafeRunnable) line: 42  
PartRenderingEngine.createGui(MUIElement) line: 685 
PartRenderingEngine$9.run() line: 1042  
Realm.runWithDefault(Realm, Runnable) line: 332 
PartRenderingEngine.run(MApplicationElement, IEclipseContext) line: 997 
E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(MApplicationElement) line: 138   
Workbench$5.run() line: 610 
Realm.runWithDefault(Realm, Runnable) line: 332 
Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Display, WorkbenchAdvisor) line: 567    
PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Display, WorkbenchAdvisor) line: 150   
Application.start(IApplicationContext) line: 32 
EclipseAppHandle.run(Object) line: 196  
EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Object) line: 110 
EclipseAppLauncher.start(Object) line: 79   
EclipseStarter.run(Object) line: 354    
EclipseStarter.run(String[], Runnable) line: 181    
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 57  
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 43  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 606  
Main.invokeFramework(String[], URL[]) line: 636 
Main.basicRun(String[]) line: 591   
Main.run(String[]) line: 1450   
Main.main(String[]) line: 1426
```

Comment: Maybe the view is marked as not closeable in the perspective. Is this your view or a standard one.

Comment: It is my view, it's configured as my other views in plugin.xml. After the window has been opened fully it's ok to hide it. Debugging this I can see this view gets `createPartControl` called when the other views do not, no idea why, and it gets created after `postWindowCreate/postWindowOpen`, stack trace hints about something about `StackRenderer`.

Comment: Did you delay the startup of your view?

Comment: Not that I know of, it also gets created even if `WorkbenchAdvisor` returns false from `openWindows`. Another interesting thing is that if I put the window under another view, it is that other view that will be opened the next time I open my application.

Comment: Trying to use an empty perspective, but after the first initial run of the application, it opens the perspective with views next time around even though I use the `-perspective` and setting it to the empty one. I can't believe it's this much work to have an empty workbench every time the application starts.

Comment: The closest I've come to success is to hide the views on `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.preWindowShellClose()`, but then next time I open my application, my toolbar is gone and I have empty views like skeletons where they were before I closed the application.

Comment: The problem might be how I hide view during startup, seems like the workbench is not created fully even in `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.postWindowOpen`, cause I get 
`org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed` when the application continues with the start up.